# There is 2 array of object with same id, but one object property is true and other property is false, how to remove both if property is false

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array of object, there is 2 array of object with same id, but one object property is true and other property is false, how to remove both if property is false.

```
[{id: 'a660f87e-476d-493b-a220-31aff8cf764c', selected: true}
{id: '1e8284a5-6ba3-48c0-b8ac-f6ffae55b44e', selected: true}
{id: 'a660f87e-476d-493b-a220-31aff8cf764c', selected: false}]
```

So this is the array but 2 object have id "a660f87e-476d-493b-a220-31aff8cf764c" and one has selected property false and another one true, so if there is false I want object with that id should remove so I need final result like this.

```
 [{id: '1e8284a5-6ba3-48c0-b8ac-f6ffae55b44e', selected: true}]
```

If array is like this

```
  [{id: 'a660f87e-476d-493b-a220-31aff8cf764c', selected: true}
    {id: '1e8284a5-6ba3-48c0-b8ac-f6ffae55b44e', selected: true}
    {id: 'a660f87e-476d-493b-a220-31aff8cf764c', selected: true}]
```

I want result as

```
    [{id: 'a660f87e-476d-493b-a220-31aff8cf764c', selected: true}
    {id: '1e8284a5-6ba3-48c0-b8ac-f6ffae55b44e', selected: true}
   ]`
```

Can anyone suggest solution .

Thanks

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

All you need is [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

If you want to select only those object whose `selected` property is true, irrespective of what value id holds then can try below snippet.

```js
let arr = [
    {id: 'a660f87e-476d-493b-a220-31aff8cf764c', selected: true},
    {id: '1e8284a5-6ba3-48c0-b8ac-f6ffae55b44e', selected: true},
    {id: '1e8284a5-6ba3-48c0-b8ac-f6ffae55b44f', selected: false},
    {id: '1e8284a5-6ba3-48c0-b8ac-f6ffae55b44e', selected: false},
    {id: 'a660f87e-476d-493b-a220-31aff8cf764c', selected: true}
]


arr = Object.values(arr.reduce( (a, b) => {
    a[b.id] = a[b.id] ? a[b.id] : b ;
    return a;
}, {})).filter(a => a.selected === true)

console.log(arr);
```

You can provide you check just like `if` condition to `filter`

Answer (score 1):

So two action items in your questions.

1. Get the items only if `selected` is true
2. If the selected `id` already available in new array then not required to include again(Like you want unique array).

you can achieve it like below.

```js
let tmp = [{id: '1', selected: true},
{id: '2', selected: true},
{id: '1', selected: true}];

var newArr = [];
var tmp1 = tmp.map((itm) => {
  var t = newArr.map(a => a.id);
    if(t.indexOf(itm.id) == -1 && itm.selected) {
    newArr.push(itm);
  }
});
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to remove object with `selected: false` from the array, right?

Maybe you can use a loop to remove the object with `selected: false`.

```
let _array = [{
        id: 'a660f87e-476d-493b-a220-31aff8cf764c',
        selected: true
    },
    {
        id: '1e8284a5-6ba3-48c0-b8ac-f6ffae55b44e',
        selected: true
    },
    {
        id: 'a660f87e-476d-493b-a220-31aff8cf764c',
        selected: false
    }
];
let temp_array = [];
_array.forEach((object, index) => {
    if (object.selected == false && hasDuplicate(object.id) == true) {
        _array.splice(index, 1);
    }
});

function hasDuplicate(id) {
    // function for finding if the element has a duplicate.
    _array.forEach(object => {
        temp_array.push(object.id)
    }); // A temporary array for storing all the ids.
    var indexes = [],
        i = -1;
    while ((i = temp_array.indexOf(id, i + 1)) != -1) {
        indexes.push(i);
    } // Finds indexes of all object with same id
    if (indexes.length > 1) {
        return true;
    } // if has more than 1 index it returns true (hasDuplicate = true)

    return false; 
}
```

In your question there is no comma (,) b/w the elements so please edit your question.

Comment: the OP's said he wanted to remove only if the id is the same

Answer (score 0):

Without using any 3rd party library, what I did was to build a dictionary where each *key* is your `id` and each *value* is `{count: <the number of ids>, isSelected: <are all ids selected>}`.

Then when I iterate the array I have 3 cases -

1. only single `id` - stay in the result.
2. more than 1 `id` but is selected is `false` - remove all.
3. more than 1 `id` but is selected is `true` - remove until we will have `count === 1`, which will fall to the first case.

```js
function extract(array) {
  let ids = {};
  array.forEach(item => {
    if (!ids[item.id])
      ids[item.id] = {
        count: 1,
        isSelected: item.selected
      };
    else {
      ids[item.id].count++;
      ids[item.id].isSelected = ids[item.id].isSelected && item.selected;
    }
  });

  return array.filter(item => {
    if (ids[item.id].count === 1) return true;
    else if (!ids[item.id].isSelected) return false;
    else ids[item.id].count--;
    return false;
  })
}

const arr1 = [{
    id: 'a660f87e-476d-493b-a220-31aff8cf764c',
    selected: true
  },
  {
    id: '1e8284a5-6ba3-48c0-b8ac-f6ffae55b44e',
    selected: true
  },
  {
    id: 'a660f87e-476d-493b-a220-31aff8cf764c',
    selected: false
  }
];

const arr2 = [{
    id: 'a660f87e-476d-493b-a220-31aff8cf764c',
    selected: true
  },
  {
    id: '1e8284a5-6ba3-48c0-b8ac-f6ffae55b44e',
    selected: true
  },
  {
    id: 'a660f87e-476d-493b-a220-31aff8cf764c',
    selected: true
  }
];


console.log(extract(arr1));
console.log(extract(arr2));
```